# Looping between two folders and perform operation with the fetched files

Tags: batch

I have to compare two excel using with .jar . However, using below code i am getting value for only one folder(MasterFolder1) and not able to get value for another folder (MasterFolder2)

```
@echo off
set /p "MasterFolder1=MasterFolder1:"
set /p "MasterFolder2=MasterFolder2:"
Set "LogFile=%~dpn0.txt"
If exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"

Set "PECfolder=C:\SunilKK-Latitude-E6430s\SunilKK\Software\PreciseExcelComparator\v1.1\PreciseExcelComparator_PEC"
PushD "%PECfolder%" || ( Echo can't locate %PECfolder% &Pause&Exit /B 0)

FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "%MasterFolder1%\*.xls"') do (
    If exist "%Masterfolder2%\%%~nxf" (
        call java -jar PEC.jar "%%~ff" "%Masterfolder2%\%%~nxf" 0 0
    ) else (
        echo No pendant to "%%f" found in "%MasterFolder2%" >> %"LogFile%"
    )
)
pause
```